# How to make a data structure for multi-level drill-down TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, data-structures, drilldown

I would like to ask you guys how to make a data structure for multi-level drill-down TableView in Swift. As of myself, I know how to do it and pass data this way **TableView -> TableView -> DetailViewController** using NSObject for creating Swift models. But several weeks now I struggle with finding of how to do this way: **TableView -> TableView -> DetailViewController -> TableView** again.

As the app I am doing now is education related, the first TableView would contain sections of topics and leesons in them, then when the user selects the lesson, the segue performs and shows content as ViewController, then the user press the button and he is redirected to another TableView with tasks related to the lesson in it. 
So in all it should be like this: **LessonsTableView -> LessonDetailViewController -> TasksTableView -> TaskDetailViewController**.

I can say that the main problem is to get the tableView of tasks listed from LessonDetailViewController. As I know how to make 2 levels of data, but can't do 3 or more.
I have searched all the internet, I have found examples in Obj-C, but simply I don't understand that programming language (tried to convert the code in XCode). Could anyone guide me of how to achieve this? Perhaps there's a link with brief tutorial that you guys know.

**Update**

I've managed to do the first TableView and ViewController, but stuck with passing data from LessonViewController to TasksTableView, getting this Error: Expression type '[Lesson]' is ambiguous without more context. 
Perhaps anyone could help me with this, my Model:

```
    import Foundation

struct task {
    var name: String
}
struct Lesson {
    var name: String
    var info: String
    var tasks: [task]
}

class LessonList {

    var name: String
    var lessons = [Lesson]()

    init(name: String, lessons: [Lesson]) {

        self.name = name
        self.lessons = lessons

    }

    class func lessonsSection() -> [LessonList] {
        return [self.intro(), self.can()]
    }

    private class func intro() -> LessonList {

        let tasks: [task] = [task(name: "hello"), task(name: "Hey")]
        let tasks1: [task] = [task(name: "is He?"), task(name: "are they?")]

        var lessons = [Lesson]()

        lessons.append(Lesson(name: "I am", info: "This class is I am", tasks: tasks))
        lessons.append(Lesson(name: "He is", info: "This class is He is", tasks: tasks1))

        return LessonList(name: "Intro", lessons: lessons)

    }

    private class func can() -> LessonList{

        let tasks: [task] = [task(name: "bye"), task(name: "can have")]
        let tasks1: [task] = [task(name: "Can he?"), task(name: "They can't")]

        var lessons = [Lesson]()

        lessons.append(Lesson(name: "I can", info: "This class is I can", tasks: tasks))
        lessons.append(Lesson(name: "He can't", info: "This class is He can't", tasks: tasks1))

        return LessonList(name: "Can", lessons: lessons)

    }

}
```

The CourseTableView (first)`import UIKit

```
class CourseTableVC: UITableViewController {

    let lessonLists : [LessonList] = LessonList.lessonsSection()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Horizon English"

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return lessonLists.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return lessonLists[section].lessons.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lessonCell", for: indexPath)

        let lessonList = lessonLists[indexPath.section]
        let lessons = lessonList.lessons
        let lesson = lessons[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = lesson.name

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        let lessonList = lessonLists[section]

        return lessonList.name

    }

    //MARK: - UITableViewdelegate, navigation segue

     var selectedLesson: Lesson?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let lessonLine = lessonLists[indexPath.section]
        var lesson = lessonLine.lessons[indexPath.row]
        selectedLesson = lesson

     }

     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

          if segue.identifier == "lessonDetailView" {

               let lessonDetailVC = segue.destination as! LessonViewController
               lessonDetailVC.lesson = selectedLesson

          }

     }

}`
```

LessonViewController **where I get error** (in prepare for segue)`import UIKit

```
class LessonViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func toTasksButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    var lesson: Lesson?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = lesson?.name
        infoLabel.text = lesson?.info

    }

    // MARK: - navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showTasks" {

            var taskTV = segue.destination as! TasksTableVC

            taskTV.tasksList = lesson?.tasks as! [Lesson]
            // Error: Expression type '[Lesson]' is ambiguous without more context
        }

    }

}`
```

and TasksTableView: `import UIKit

```
class TasksTableVC: UITableViewController {

    var tasksList = [Lesson]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Tasks"

    }

      // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasksList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath)

        let taskList = tasksList[indexPath.section]
        let tasks = taskList.tasks
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: task)

        return cell
    }

}`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a pictorial representation or a screenshot and explain it side by side. It's really hard to understand it like this

Comment: Hey, I've took Valcanaia's suggestion and did it with structs, all works fine till the the segue in LessonViewController file, the error I am getting is  "Expression type '[Lesson]' is ambiguous without more context". Perhaps you know how to solve it?

Comment: This type of error usually happens when compiler doesn't have enough information about your custom type. For example, you explicitly casted your array as [Lesson]? but it should have been [Lesson]. I'm just saying, don't take it literally in context with your code. So you need to verify types and explicitly define it, where you were thinking compiler should do it for you. Edit your question, I'll have a look at it

Comment: Why cast a task array as a lesson array? Just pass `lessons.task` to an empty `task` array.

Answer (score 0):

**I can say that the main problem is to get the tableView of tasks listed from LessonDetailViewController.**

I don't know what steps you already did so I'll say how I'd do it:

1 - Have the structure implemented. That's my suggestion:

```
struct Task {
    var name = ""
}
struct Lesson {
    var name = ""
    var tasks: [Tasks] // list of tasks for this lesson
}
```

OR

```
struct Task {
    var name = ""
    var lesson: Lesson // the leasson which the task belongs to
}
struct Lesson {
    var name = ""
}
```

2 - I suppose you know how to pass data between view controllers, so when the user select the cell of the lesson he wants, you'd pass the lesson object to the `LessonDetailVC` and show the data. Something like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedLesson = lessons[indexPath.row]
    // code to pass to the next vc here or in prepareForSegue
}
```

3 - To create the tableview for the tasks you just have to filter(or query, or fetch, I don't know how you're getting the data) in order to obtaining the tasks. Let's suposed you used the first code from item 1 so you just simply show the `lesson.tasks` array in your table view. If you chose the second code from item 1 you will have to perform some query with a filter passing the lesson your in, something like `query.where("lesson", lesson)` and you will have the tasks array.

**UPDATE**

Since you're new on `Swift` here's an idea on how to model your view controller:

```
// Your models
struct Task {
    var name = ""
    var lesson: Lesson // the leasson which the task belongs to
}

struct Lesson {
    var name = ""
}

// This is just a DataManager to help you get your data
class DataManager {

    func getLessons() -> [Lesson]? {
        return [Lesson(name: "Lesson 1"), Lesson(name: "Lesson 2"), Lesson(name: "Lesson 3")]
    }

    func getTasks(for lesson: Lesson) -> [Task]? {
        guard let lessons = getLessons() else {
            return nil
        }

        let allTasks = [
            Task(name: "T1", lesson: lessons[0]),
            Task(name: "T2", lesson: lessons[0]),
            Task(name: "T3", lesson: lessons[0]),

            Task(name: "T1", lesson: lessons[1]),
            Task(name: "T2", lesson: lessons[1]),

            Task(name: "T1", lesson: lessons[2]),
            Task(name: "T2", lesson: lessons[2]),
            Task(name: "T3", lesson: lessons[2]),
            Task(name: "T4", lesson: lessons[2])
        ]

        return allTasks.filter{ $0.lesson == lesson }
    }

}

class LessonsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private var lessons: [Lesson]? {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    private var selectedLesson: Lesson?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        lessons = DataManager().getLessons()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lessons?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lessonCell", for: indexPath)

        let lesson = lessons[indexPath.section]
        cell.textLabel?.text = lesson.name

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var lesson = lessons[indexPath.row]
        selectedLesson = lesson
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "lessonDetailView" {
            let lessonDetailVC = segue.destination as! LessonViewController
            if selectedLesson != nil {
                lessonDetailVC.lesson = selectedLesson!
            }
        }
    }

}

class TasksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    var lesson: Lesson!
    private var tasks: [Task]? {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tasks = DataManager().getTasks(for: lesson)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I suppose it should be done like this. But the problem is that I am new to Swift and I don't know how to append tasks to Lesson. Should I create a function or class? Or a separate model file where the things will be done?

Comment: You can do this the way will feel comfortable doing. I mean, it depends on how your API for getting the data works, when you need this data, how you wanna present, etc. I just updated the answer with one way of doing this. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking time and writing all that code. That's truly nice. That's a good example as I am a bit lacking practical programming knowledge on some things, especially when mainly learned 'dry' theory .  I did copy your code to see how it works, and I am getting error in the line where is 'return allTasks.filter { $0.lesson == lesson}' ()DataManager class), the error message is "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Lesson' operands". Any idea of how to solve this? Cheers

Comment: This happens because Lesson is not Equatable, meaning you can’t use == to compare 2 instances of it. You can use this code to have some basis but you should write your own code also for practice.

Comment: Alright mate, thanks. Will figure out how to do it, or perhaps I have to rethink the app I want to make and make it more simplified. But you helped me a lot by giving some good insights. cheers.